# How to calculate lengths in this specific geometric figure

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

[image: geometry]

The attached figure represents a steering mechanism, with wheels attached to A and B and the steering momentum applied to X.

The points A, B and X are fixed and cannot be moved.
The following has to be true:

- x < a1
- x < b1
- a != b
- a1 || b1

If the angle at the point X is 90° the same has to be the case at A and B.
But for every other angle X is irrelevant.

How do I have to choose the lengths of a1, a2, b1 and b2 to fullfill these requirements ?

Thanks in advance :D

Edit: The lines a1,b1 and x have to be rotated around their according Points in the range of 10° < x < 170° to make the actual steering happen, look at the rotated figure for reference

[image: rotated geometry]

Comment: it is not clear what your problem is. In particular, what is the matter with the angle in X? what is "a != b"?

Comment: a != b means the point X cannot lie in the middle between A and B, there is a slight offset.

Comment: The angle at X has to only be the same as the angles at A and B for 90°(like in the figure)

Comment: @ dxiv  the Problem with this is the lines a1,b1 and x have to be rotated around their according Points (sorry for not clarifying), and with any a1 and b1 this statement: a1 || b1 would be violated

Comment: @J.Kieser Don't see a "nice" solution offhand. The laborious way, let $A_1,X_1,B_1$ be the corresponding points on the zigzag at the top, and $\varphi = \angle AXX_1\,$. Then quadrilaterals $AXX_1A_1$ and $XBB_1X_1$ can be solved in terms of $a,b,x,a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,\varphi\,$. The condition $\angle A_1AX + \angle XBB_1 = 180^\circ$ for $\forall \varphi$ will give a couple of relations between the other variables. $\varphi = 90^\circ \implies \angle A_1AX = 90^\circ$ will give another relation. The range $[10^\circ,170^\circ]$ will give some bounds. None of that too pretty, though.

Comment: Did you get the solution? Still interested?

Comment: Sorry for not commenting for a long time, I am still interested in a solution, but I can not solve it on my own.  @dxiv several Relations would be a good starting point, if you are still interested